# Why numpy.exp returns a pandas.Series object when the argument is a Pandas.Series object?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

With the following python code:

```
s = [0, 1, 2, 3]
s_np= randn(5)
s_pd = pd.Series(randn(5))

print s.__class__, " -> ", np.exp(s).__class__
print s_np.__class__, " -> ", np.exp(s_np).__class__
print s_pd.__class__, " -> ", np.exp(s_pd).__class__
```

I got the following output:

```
<type 'list'>  ->  <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>  ->  <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>  ->  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

According to the document of `np.exp`, it should return an `ndarray`. But apparently it returns a pandas `Series` object when the argument is pandas `Series` object.

If I understand it correctly, numpy doesn't even know the `Series` class, because it's a lower level class where Pandas was built upon. What magic is happening here?

Thanks ;-)

Comment: Basically, the pandas team built their objects to be mostly compatible with numpy arrays. It's a design choice and feature of pandas.

Comment: Thanks Paul. That amazed me. If I want to implement a function with similar behaviors, how could I do that? The function should return a `ndarray` for `list` and `ndarry`, and return a `Series` when the input is a `Series`. And I couldn't use the class `Series` in the function.

Comment: what version of pandas?

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.classes.html#special-attributes-and-methods).

Comment: Thanks guys. According to the link that Jaime provided, `__numpy_ufunc__` is a new thing in `Numpy` 1.9. I am using `Numpy` 1.8.1 and `Pandas` 0.13.1 though, in which `Series` is inherited from `NDFrame` instead of `ndarray`.

Comment: It not the `__numpy_ufunc__` but the `__array__` and `__array_wrap__` method, here is the source code of `Series`: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py#L368